# Laravel 5 : Optional parameter in routes

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I am looking for a solution for this code to work with the optional parameter.Indeed placed at the beginning, this parameter is no longer considered optional but I absolutely need to have a solution.

The goal is to archive the old versions of the website by year (it's for a music festival) without having to duplicate all laravel files ...

```
Route::get('{year?}/lineup', 'HomeController@agenda')->name('agenda');
```

In this precise case :

```
/2018/lineup => works
/lineup => not working
```

Note : I'm using Laravel 5.4

An idea, a suggestion to archive by date the old versions of the site ?
Archives must be accessible online.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just first check for the full route with the year, if you get no match then move on to the one without the year and send them to the same controller?

Comment: OOps :-) Thank Dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add them in this order it should first check for a match with the year and then for only the lineup. Then it is up to your controller (same for both routes, no extra files needed) to handle the input parameter, if it is set or not.

```
Route::get('{year}/lineup', 'HomeController@agenda')->name('agenda.history');
Route::get('lineup', 'HomeController@agenda')->name('agenda.current');
```